# Shared variable across applications within the same AppPool?

Tags: c#, asp.net, application-pool

I'm using `Asp.net` FW 4.6.

I have two applications under the same application pool that need to read (constantly) a predefined value which is object to change.

Static variables can't be used because different apps (even under same app pool) - won't be shared.

DB/File/Server are known options.

But :

**Question :**

Is there any code that I can write that can store in mem value which will be accessible through multiple applications which are under the same App Pool ?

Something like :

```
MyAppPool  

    App1   -> func("royi") = 1
    App2   -> var a= func2("royi"); //1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All ways of interprocess communication, such as [Memory Mapped Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/memory-mapped-files) and [Named Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes?view=netframework-4.7) can also be used for sharing data across applications within single AppPool, see for example [Sharing memory between two applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894224/sharing-memory-between-two-applications).

Because all apps in the same AppPool resides in the same process and are separated just by AppDomain boundaries, you have some additional options:

- Use
  [MarshalByRefObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.marshalbyrefobject?view=netframework-4.7)
  to access object instance across AppDomain boundaries. There are
  already available wrappers that uses MarshalByRefObject to implement
  cross-AppDomain singleton, for example [Stephen
  Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)'s
  [CrossDomainSingleton](https://github.com/StephenCleary/CrossDomainSingleton/blob/master/Source/DomainAwareSingleton/Singleton.cs)
  or [this
  one](http://web.archive.org/web/20120127141002/http://www.dolittle.com/blogs/einar/archive/2007/05/18/cross-appdomain-singleton.aspx).
- Use pointers and [unsafe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unsafe) code to directly access memory allocated by [Marshal.AllocHGlobal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=netframework-4.7#System_Runtime_InteropServices_Marshal_AllocHGlobal_System_Int32_), especially if speed is your concern. But you will have to use one of the aforementioned methods to share memory address of allocated memory between applications.

Comment: The MarshalByRefObject implementations you mentioned are for applications with several appDomains not for different applications in the same app pool. I spent several hours trying to make it work and could never see the other AppDomains.

Comment: @achecopar *IIS* uses *AppDomains* to isolate individual applications (within an *AppPool*) from each other. Or at least it is how it worked on *IIS 7.5* years ago, when I successfully used [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jackg/enumerating-appdomains) technique to enumerate *AppDomains* belonging to other applications and *MarshalByRefObject* for communication between these *AppDomains*. But things might have changed since then.